# jquery ui slider storing value in a var

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

hey I have a slider set up using jquery ui, and for some reason I can't get the basic set up of having a slider, range 1-3, and then when the slider is moved having that current value displayed in a div, for some reason the numbers it displays aren't in order 1,2,3.

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vG8NY/14/

code is as follows:

html:

```
<div id="variable_slider"></div>
<div id="slide"></div>
```

js:

```
 $("#variable_slider").slider({
     value: 2,
     range: "min",
     min: 1,
     max: 3,
     step: 1,
     slide: function (event, ui) {
         slider_value = $("#variable_slider").slider("value");
         $("#slide").html(slider_value);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 $("#variable_slider").slider({
     value: 2,
     range: "min",
     min: 1,
     max: 3,
     step: 1,
     slide: function (event, ui) {
         slider_value = ui.value;
         $("#slide").html(slider_value);
     }
 });
```

Whereas the important part is:

```
slider_value = ui.value;
```

**Why?**

*ui* is already providing a reference to your slider object, and its property *.value* contains the correct value.

See [this page](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical) for an example implementation.

Comment: what if you had multiple sliders?

Comment: Its fine by itself - the callback will be applied to each slider that matches your selector. *ui* will always be a reference to the current slider. If however you would like to perform certain actions within that callback, actions which refer to values of other sliders, that doesn't make sense as a slider needs to be used in order for the slide-event to fire. And its rather improbable that two sliders are going to be used in accord.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
slider_value = $("#variable_slider").slider("value");
$("#slide").html(slider_value);
```

with:

```
$("#slide").html(ui.value);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vG8NY/15/)**

Comment: The reason you are getting the wrong values is because the slider value does not update until the change event. During the slide event, the value of the slider is still the previous value.